# Choosing script writer/editor in QGIS Script Runner Preferences

Tags: qgis-plugins

I am a beginner to QGIS and have recently installed QGIS ver.3.82 onto my Windows OS laptop. I have downloaded the Script Runner plugin.

I want to use my favorite my script writer/editor (either PythonWin or Notepad++) to use as default for QGIS using the Script Runner Preferences from the toolbar menu: Plugins>Script Runner>Script Runner Version 3.05 window.

I then click-on the Preferences icon to open Script Runner Preferences window.

I click-on the check box enabling me to select my chosen script writer/editor to use as default by clicking on the three dots on the right (...) After this, another window opens allowing the user to select their chosen script writer/editor.

However, this method isn't working. After the new window for selection of our chosen script writer/editor appears. No matter whether I select my favorite script writer/editor, then click-on OPEN or whether I click-on CANCEL. I still receive the same frustrating Python error notification in a new window:

```
An error has occurred executing Python code:

Type Error: setText(self, str: Argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple' 

Python version 3.7.0 (v.3.7.0:...) 
QGIS version 3.8.2 - Zanzibar ...
```

This very strange and frustrating. Because I am only trying to choose my favorite Python writer/editor as default in relation to QGIS. And no matter whether I choose my favorite with OPEN or click-on Cancel. The frustrating Python error notification still appears.

Comment: Suggest you submit an issue to the developer - https://github.com/g-sherman/Script-Runner/issues

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write manually path to your favourite text editor, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```